# How to repeat the last Rasa bot utterance

Tags: python, rasa-core

For a bot which is used mainly via voice, I would like to be able to repeat the last message the bot said. So for example:

```
Bot: I found contact ABC with phone number 123456 
User: Could you please repeat that? 
Bot: I found contact ABC with phone number 123456
```

I do not want to repeat the whole action (searching in the database for the contact information), but only repeat the output of the bot again.

I thought I could create a slot “last_message” and fill that slot always in all my custom actions. However maintaining this slot manually is quite tedious. Is there a more elegant solution to simply repeat the last message the bot said?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if len(tracker.events) >= 3:
   dispatcher.utter_message(tracker.events[-3].get('text'))
   return[]
```

But it only works if the message is 3 events back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that repeats all the messages till the last user input without any hardcoding. This works well for text and buttons. You can do the same for images.

class ActionRepeat(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_repeat"

```
def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

    user_ignore_count = 2
    count = 0
    tracker_list = []

    while user_ignore_count > 0:
        event = tracker.events[count].get('event')
        if event == 'user':
            user_ignore_count = user_ignore_count - 1
        if event == 'bot':
            tracker_list.append(tracker.events[count])
        count = count - 1

    i = len(tracker_list) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        data = tracker_list[i].get('data')
        if data:
            if "buttons" in data:
                dispatcher.utter_message(text=tracker_list[i].get('text'), buttons=data["buttons"])
            else:
                dispatcher.utter_message(text=tracker_list[i].get('text'))
        i -= 1

    return []
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following in your action code

```
query = tracker.latest_message.get('text')

dispatcher.utter_message(query)
```

Comment: But this returns the last user message. What I need is the last bot message.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, I've been trying to figure this out as well, although I was going to do it with the slot method you stated however I though that was tedious as well